# How assistant model works in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I build a new class called `StaticCellTableViewController`. Now I want to connect some element from the `Main.storyboard` to it. But I can't have these two windows side by side.

I go the `StaticCellTableViewController` and click assistant. It gives me two `StaticCellTableViewController` windows.

[image]

I try to click assistant in the `Main.storyboard` window. It gives me another class like this.

[image]

But I want the `Main.storyboard` window and the `StaticCellTableViewController` class side by side so I can drag elements to it. How can I do that?

Comment: Click the top left, where it says Automatic. This brings up a list of files to open. You can then select the right one

Comment: I can't find the class that I want. It has only 1 class, which is `UIResponder.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Assistant any more. Don’t use it. Editor panes can now contain anything.

So open two normal editor panes. Click in one pane. Click your view controller in the navigator. Click in the other pane. Click your storyboard in the navigator. Done.